# Face recognition for large number of people

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am building a face-recognition for a large number of people and I when to detect more and more when I add more data to train the model.
My current pipeline is:

1. Detecting faces with Yolov4-tiny
2. Recognize faces with KNN classifier (I train it with around 80 classes with each class contains around 5 pictures)

Currently, it can run in real-time with around 10fps on CPU. My concern is that through some research, I found that KNN will have problems if I increase the dataset (the curse of dimensionality). So i would like to know if it is ok for using KNN for this problem ? If not is there a way around this or another way to sort this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the dataset does not cause the curse of dimensionality. The curse of dimensionality occurs in high dimensional spaces for example when using a large number of features. Increasing the dataset has instead a positive effect.

I do see a problem in only using 5 pictures per class.

Also if you are interested in real-time performance (usually people mean 30fps+ when talking about real-time), I would look into running yolov4-tiny on a GPU instead of a CPU if that is possible.

Comment: Yeah I going to switch it to GPU eventually so that's why i consider 10fps on CPU is real time. By what you saying if the image is too large then the curse of dimensionality happens ?

Comment: Yes. What I would suggest is after you detected a face with yolov4-tiny, that you first extract features from the face (say 50 features). Then I would use the KNN on those features. The paper "Face recognition using bagging KNN" by Ebrahimpour and Kouzani is an example of using a KNN for face recognition. I think you can freely acces this paper by using google scholar.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to study approximate nearest neighbor algorithm instead of k-nn. Those are the popular a-nn libraries: [Spotify Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy), [Facebook Faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) and [NMSLIB](https://github.com/nmslib/nmslib). Besides, Elasticsearch wraps NMSLIB and it offers highly scalability. Those libraries reduces the complexity dramatically. You can even search identities just in milliseconds among millions or billions items. Of course, you have to apply pre-processing for your data base images.